# Progressive web app works offline in Firefox but not chrome, causes? Webserver issues?

Tags: cross-browser, webserver, progressive-web-apps

I'm having a peculiar problem and I can't wrap my head around why it may be happening. Please if anyone has experienced something similar and has a work around I'd appreciate it.

I have a development server set up locally. I use xampp and have https set up and all.   So my local development content is served up from the server with an address such as  https://local-site.test/

I also have my production environment which I deploy my site to on a shared hosting server which is  set up as https://production-site.com

My file structure is identical for both the local (development) site as well as the production site.  So I don't have any issues with paths or folder structures being different from one environment to the next. It is identical.

When I run my app on the local development server, it works perfectly. All the pages are cached (both static and dynamic) and when I simulate being offline,  the cached pages are returned. (It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Opera)

However, when I port the files to my production server,  I get a warning notice in the manifest tab that chrome cannot display all the icons. (under the Installability section). This was not a problem on my local servers. There are three icons all located in the same folder and called from the json manifest file which it could call and display.

On the production servers it only shows the first one which is 192x192.    It doesn't display the other two that are 256 and 512px.   On the local server it displayed all three and they are all being served from the same location.

Still, when I run the lighthouse audits for pwa,  my app passes all tests. And on all the devices I've visited my app on, I've been able to install the app when I get an install banner prompt from chrome to install the page to my home screen. So I"m able to successfully install the apps on phones and tablets from my live servers.

The main problem though is when I navigate from page to page, I see all the caches being created - both static and dynamic, but when I go to airplane mode, or use the offline simulator, it keeps saying the page is offline.

I can't for the life of me figure out what could be causing the problem, except if there are possible web server configurations that could be affecting it.

Below are screen shots and the code I'm using.  (Like I said, my set ups for both local and production content are identical, so nothing is different in what I'm doing on either end). It works great on my test server but on the shared hosting server it has the issues mentioned.

```
    {
        "name": "My site",
        "short_name": "Site",
        "icons": [
            {
                "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
                "sizes": "192x192",
                "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
                "src": "android-chrome-256x256.png",
                "sizes": "256x256",
                "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
                "src": "android-chrome-512x512.png",
                "sizes": "512x512",
                "type": "image/png"
            }
        ],
        "theme_color": "#0A78A8",
        "background_color": "#ffffff",
        "start_url": "/",
        "scope": "/",
        "description":"The short description",
        "display": "standalone",
        "dir":"ltr",
        "lang":"en_US"
    }
```

Above is my manifest.json file.

```
    let CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v1';
    let CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v1';

    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
                .then(function (cache) {
                  return  cache.addAll([
                        '/',
                        '/assets/img/logo-white-name-200-long.png',
                        '/assets/css/styles.css',
                        '/assets/css/fonts/icofont.woff',
                        '/assets/css/fonts/icofont.woff2',
                        '/assets/fonts/michroma.woff2',
                        '/assets/fonts/roboto-italic.woff2',
                        '/assets/fonts/roboto.woff2',
                        '/assets/js/fetch.js',
                        '/assets/js/promise.js',
                        '/assets/js/global-app.js',
                        '/assets/css/img/home/home-hero-800.jpg'
                    ]);
                })

        )
    });


    self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.keys()
                .then(function (keyList) {
                    return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
                        if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
                            return caches.delete(key);
                        }
                    }));
                })
        );
        return self.clients.claim();
    });


    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        return response;
                    }
                    else {
                        return fetch(event.request) 
                            .then(function (res) {
                                return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                                    .then(function (cache) {
                                        cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                                        return res;
                                    })
                            })
                            .catch(function (err) {

                            }); 

                    }
                })
        );
    });
```

Above is my service worker file

[warning on chrome dev tools that manifest could not load two of the icons. It loaded all three icons successfully on development web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAOom.png)

[This is dev tools showing that my content is being cached in local storage on page visits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo8S4.png)

[Lighthouse PWA audit, my app passes all tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxPL7.png)

I'm able to install the app on different phones and tablets after  the second visit upon getting the "install banner prompt from chrome", from the production server. But it doesn't serve up any of the cached content from the service workers when I try to view content offline.

Just to add something else, I have called up my web hosts and gone through the whole scenario on their end and they can't see any reason from their side that could be blocking the files from showing offline.

Also, when I test it all out on Firefox - both on a desktop and mobile device, it works perfectly. I can access all the pages in offline mode or airplane mode.

It's really baffling. Only on chrome and opera (which also uses the chrome rendering engine) that it fails to work in offline mode.

I would appreciate any help if somebody can identify what could be causing the problem.

I know it's a lengthy post, but I tried to post as much information to help with debugging the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So, I have finally figured out what was preventing my Progressive Web App from working in offline mode in the Chrome and Opera browsers which use the same rendering engine.

On my production servers, I was using gzip/mod_deflate to send my page files and scripts to the browser in a compressed form.  This is an optimization technique that's generally recommended. Speeds up downloads of the files and the browser can unzip them.

I had the following files zipped up by gzip/mod_deflate

text/html text/plain text/xml text/css  application/x-javascript application/javascript

Like I said when I first posed the question, with the same settings, my app worked flawlessly in offline mode on Firefox!   However, for chrome it only seems to work now when I use mod_gzip  and not mod_deflate for compression.